# ColdFusion Web Poll - Update poll results in MS Access Database

Tags: coldfusion

How can I code when option1 is selected to update access db with + 1 vote.  Database only has one record with Option1, Option2, Option3 & etc in each column.  The total vote count will display under each column based on which option is choosen.

Answer (score 1):

> *Database only has one record with
>   Option1, Option2, Option3*

The biggest problem is your table structure. Manipulating the data would be far easier if the options were stored in rows (not columns). For a very simple table, insert each option as a separate row, initialized with 0 votes:

```
   RecordID | OptionName | TotalVotes
   1        | T-Shirt 1  | 0 
   2        | T-Shirt 2  | 0 
   3        | T-Shirt 3  | 0 
   .... 
   5        | T-Shirt 5 | 0
```

Then use the results of your SELECT query to populate your form (or display the totals if needed):

```
<cfoutput query="poll">
     <input type="radio" name="TshirtOption" value="#RecordID#"> #OptionName#
     ... 
</cfoutput>
```

When the form is submitted, increment the total votes for the selected option. Add validation of course.

```
<cfquery name="updateVote" datasource="fiteastpoll">
     UPDATE  Tshirt_poll
     SET     TotalVotes = TotalVotes + 1
     WHERE   RecordID = <cfqueryparam value="#form.TshirtOption#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
</cfquery>
```

Answer (score -2):

I am assuming submitted option comes as form variable with name selectedOption and try below query...

```
<cfquery name="qUpdate" datasource="datasourcename">
Update TShirt_port set option#form.selectedOption# = option#form.selectedOption# + 1
</cfquery>
```

Comment: What about queryparams and not using form/url variables directly in the query?