# Radio Button-Variable Undefined Error

Tags: coldfusion, radio-button

I keep getting this "Element TSHIRTOPTION is undefined in Form" Error when page first loads up.  The radio button values work when I click on each one.  When  I refresh the browser, error doesnt appear again until I click on link again (like when the page loads up the first time).  I have one of the radio buttons "preselected" hoping to solve the  undefined error, but no help there.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please update it to include the code causing the error. It also seems very similar to this thread, it is yours too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596339/coldfusion-web-poll-update-poll-results-in-ms-access-database

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things could be happening here:

1. your query is running before the form is submitted - make sure your UPDATE only executes after the form is submitted  run query
2. you are trying to use the form.TshirtOption variable before it is defined as in the radio button itself:

<cfif form.TshirtOption is "radio"><cfset checked = 'checked="checked"'/></cfif>

<input name="radio" type="radio" id="radio" value="radio" #checked# />

OR - you are trying to use the variable out of scope i.e. form.TshirtOption vs TshirtOption

we might need to see your full source, but basically you probably need to give the variable a default before you try to use it:
<cfparam name="form.TshirtOption" value="" />

-sean

Answer (score 0):

Code would be helpful, but I bet a

`<cfparam name="form.TSHIRTOPTION " default="your_default_value"/>`

at the top of the page would fix you right up.  :)